# Continuity and the existence of the limits

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

This question is due to a clarification asked by an engineer friend. Supposing that I have this function

$$f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2} \tag 1$$

that it is simply a semicircle in the first and second quadrant with the domain $[-1;1]$ and $f([-1;1])=\operatorname{im} f=[0;1]$. One of his students of an high school thinks that at point $-1$ and $1$ the function is not continuous, because

$$\bbox[pink,5px,border:2px solid lightgray]{\lim_{x\to (-1)^-}f(x)=\nexists, \quad \lim_{x\to (-1)^+}f(x)=0}$$

($ (-1)^-$ it is out of the domain). I think instead that it is true that $ (-1)^-$ it is out from the domain but are true the two conditions:

\begin{cases}
-1 \in \mathrm{dom}\, f(x), \\
\lim_{x\to (-1)^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to (-1)^+}f(x)=f(-1)=0
\end{cases}
The same procedure for $1$.

> Is it correct or are there specific other observations?

Comment: I personally would say the $f$ is continuous for the induced topology on $[-1,1]$. Continuity is implicitly relative to the domain. Cheers! :-)

Comment: @Bernard Hi, $\ddot \smile$. Yes I have seen your observation on wikipedia in Italian language $\ddot \smile$. But I not remember the concept of "induced topology".

Comment: Open sets are simply the intersection of open sets in $\mathbf R$ with the domain. So an open set of $[-1,1]$ may be  a closed or a semi-open set in $\mathbf R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function $f\left(x\right)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ *is* continuous as the composition of continuous functions.

Remember that function $f$ is continuous at the point $x_0\in\mathrm{dom}(f)$ if the limit of $f\left(x\right)$, as $x$ approaches $x_0$ *through the domain* of $f$, exists and is equal to $f\left(x_0\right)$. As you can see, definition (or characterization) says that variable $x$ must approach through the domain.

Comment: I'm agree with you and I approved. When do you write "...$x$ approaches $x_0$...." in the Italian textbooks there is not this observation. Can you edit your answer, please, and can you put a (the) reference/s of a book?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking me. *Mathematical Analysis I* and *II* form author Vladimir Zorich give precise definitions of limits and continuity.  These two books are probably the best introduction to Analysis I ever read.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funzione_continua#Definizione_in_termini_di_limite_di_una_funzione).

The limits the student is talking about simply makes no sense. Left limit at $x=-1$ or right limit at $x=1$ are nonsensical, like, for instance, limit at $x=1000$.

This is expressed by the sentence

"essa [la definizione] ha senso solo se $p$ è un **punto di accumulazione** per il dominio di $f$"

My daughter's math teacher says the same nonsense, like $\frac{1}{x}$ is not continuous because doesn't exist at $x=0$. This is WRONG.

Hope this can help

Comment: Very good the explanation also in Italian language $\ddot\smile$ $\ddot\smile$ $\ddot\smile$ $\ddot\smile$ and I had seen before the question the same your link. Just to be fair I didn't see or don't remember that it talks about accumulation point in continuity but obviously when you calculate a limit generally in fifth year textbooks it is implied that the point is accumulation. But I have seen with my own eyes that many teachers ignore these definitions that I carry out and treat in limits of functions. +1

Comment: @Sebastiano Purtroppo molte prof di quinta sono prof di fisica ARGHHH!